# Validating a collada file beyond simple schema validation

Tags: validation, blender, collada

I'm working on a tool that can export skinned meshes in Collada format. I've tried to ensure that my export follows the layout shown here: https://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/Skinning.

Somehow, somewhere I must have made a mistake, because when try to import the skinned mesh into blender, I get an error on the console stating: 'Cannot find skin by controller data UID." Unfortunately I cannot tell from that message what my mistake is.

Is there some tool I can use to validate the Collada file, beyond what "simple" XML schema validation can do?

I even went so far as to download the sources for Blender and extended on the information Blender gives, unfortunately I failed to produce a working binary. It compiled, but could not run.

Ideally I'd like to know if there is a better tool for validating my Collada file, and failing that, to know what - specifically - Blender is objecting to when it produces that error message.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error I found the issue. My Joint list source turned out to be invalid.

It would appear that the way the Blender Collada importer works is:

1) Load the sources relevant to skinning (drop any invalid sources)
2) Process the sources

Which means that Blender, almost regardless of which source fails, almost always will issue the same warning whenever any source needed for skinning is invalid.